# Fedora13 | Remove X Window System and Disable it

Tags: yum, fedora

I have installed Fedora13, i have removed X Window System by "Yum remove 'x window system'"

Have edited /etc/inittab to boot to init3 (command line)

Now, whenever I do a yum update, it checks for all the x-window system related packages, is there a way I can disable YUM to look for any packages related to gui (x window).

Will be grateful for your input / help
Kind Regards

Comment: Did you use the grouplist/groupremove commands to remove all x windows system?

Comment: sudo yum groupremove "X Window System"
I used the above command to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll struggle to remove *every* vestige of the X Window system.

For example, graphics packages tend to support X pixmaps, so you end up with `libXpm`, `libX11` and various other X11 libraries.

On my headless machines that means I still have X, for stuff like ImageMagick, gtk2, ghostscript, cairo, etc.

Comment: So basically that's not worth doing it then - rather using a server based distro ? like centos or ubuntu server ?

isnt' there a fedora server version ?

Comment: Fedora server version could be classified as CentOS.  Fedora was spawned from Redhat leaving the desktop arena, Redhat now do Redhat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) for servers and CentOS is the spin off from RHEL.

Comment: So, Fedora being a desktop distro it is not going to be easy to remove the desktop element. :)  As you say, use a server distro.

Answer (score 1):

sudo yum remove xorg-x11 try this it work!

Comment: Have already removed it, what I am after is as follows :
When after removal, you do a "yum update" it shouldn't check for x-window related packages, like when I do a yum update now, it shows me a 315MB download - basically downloading all again - which I want to avoid. any suggestions ? 

Thanks for your input !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the exclude-package option when running yum (or inside the conf file). Although you probably have some other packages installed that has a dependency on some of the X Window files.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora uses basically the same package set, with the same deps., as RHEL-5 or RHEL-6. So you can get a server like install going with 200 packages or so, however just removing the "X Window System" group won't get you very far. What I tend to do (if I don't just kickstart install with @core and yum) is to go straight  for a core dependency, with something like:

```
yum remove libX11
```

...and then see what is left, and work from there.